# How to encrypt csv/xlsx file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, prawn

I am want to implement password protection to my csv/xlsx file, but somehow not able to. I am not able to find something written well over the internet. I tried this with xlsx.

```rb
render formats: :xlsx if current_user.save(validate: false)
```

In my `app/views/tools/export_database.xlsx.axlsx`

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook

wb.add_worksheet(name: "Users") do |sheet|
    sheet.sheet_protection.password = ENV['sheet_password']
    sheet.add_row %w(Id Email Role Verification First\ Name Last\ Name Title Birthday Postcode Telephone Payment Company\ Name Office\ Number Address Email\ Confirmed Agent\ Name Agent\ Position Agent\ Number Agent\ Email Company\ Logo Address\ Line\ 2 Town County Created\ At Updated\ At), :types => [:string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string]
    User.all.each do |user|
        sheet.add_row [user.id, user.email, user.role, user.verification, user.first_name, user.last_name, user.title, user.dob, user.postcode, user.telephone, user.payment, user.company_name, user.office_number, user.address, user.email_confirmed, user.agent_name, user.agent_position, user.agent_number, user.agent_email, user.company_logo, user.address_line_two, user.town, user.county, user.created_at, user.updated_at], :types => [:string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string, :string]
    end
end
```

But this is not working.

Another implementation is with CSV.

```rb
format.csv { send_data @users.to_csv, filename: "users-#{Date.today}.csv" }
```

In user model.

```rb
CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes

      all.find_each do |user|
        csv << attributes.map{ |attr| user.send(attr) }
      end
    end
```

In this, I couldn't find how to add password.

There is another way tried that is with [prawn](https://github.com/cortiz/prawn-rails) and [prawn-table](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn-table) but the problem is that, when number of columns increase, the table doesn't look good. Please help me with any of the above methods. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Where do you set the value of 'sheet_password'?

Answer (score 0):

While Excel files have support for password protection, CSV do not. So abandon the CSV approach.

The gem you’re using to generate the xlsx supports password encrypting and has an example here https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx/blob/282eec44ef01746ee25931fa6cd287ad083fd40b/examples/sheet_protection_example.md

When you say that it’s not working; in what way is it not working? Failing to generate the file or it generated the file but it’s not protected?

Comment: the file generated is not password protected. I can open it on google sheets and elsewhere.